# How to add a <br/> tag on the last word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, menu

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I add a `<br>`tag on the last element of the a tag using jQuery making the above example as follows:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu <br/>One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu <br/>Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to use this code but it only adding a `<br/>` tag on the first word:

```js
$('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').each(function() {
  var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
  html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
  $(this).html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like what you want is:

```
$('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
    html = html.slice(0, -1).join(" ") + " <br />" + html.pop();
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Which only places the `<br>` tag before the last word, and no other words.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach:

```
$('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').html(function(html) {
    var words = $(this).html().split(/\s+/);
    words.splice(-1, 0, '<br>');
    return words.join(' ');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rvgfx32q/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzL9fnmt/)

```
    $('ul > li > a').each(function() {
     var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
     //html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
     html = html.join("<br>");
     $(this).html(html);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/wcLsm6fd/

```
$('ul  li').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).find('a').html().split(" ");
    html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works :

```
$("ul > li > a").html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/ /g, '<br/>');
});
```